# JSTree Limit Drag and Drop Depth

Tags: javascript, django, jstree

I'm working on a web page which I'm building with Django. I'm trying to use jsTree to allow the user to assign samples to different locations. The root nodes are the locations, and the leaf nodes are the samples. The samples start in a location labeled "UNKNOWN", and I want the users to be able to add new locations and then drag the samples into the correct location.

```
UNKNOWN
    Sample 1
    Sample 2
    Sample 3
Location 1
Location 2
```

So far I haven't added any locations to the tree, so there is only UNKNOWN

This is where I create the tree through html in a Django template:

```
<div id="demo1" class="demo" style="height:500px;width:500px">
<ul>
    {% for key, value in samples.items %}
    <li id="{{key}}">
        <a href="#">{{key}}</a>
        <ul>
            {% for key2, value2 in value.items %}
            <li id="{{key2}}">
                <a href="#">{{key2}}: {{value2}}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

This gets turned into the following html (taken from firebug):

```
<div id="demo1" class="demo" style="height:500px;width:500px">
    <ul>
        <li id="UNKNOWN">
            <a href="#">UNKNOWN</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="3511904">
                    <a href="#">3511904: ECKD 06-10-061-22W5M</a>
                </li>

                <li id="3511905">
                    <a href="#">3511905: WCKD 06-10-061-22W5M</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All I have in the Javascript so far is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({
        "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","hotkeys","dnd"],
        "core" : { "initially_open" : [ {% for key, value in samples.items %}"{{key}}", {% endfor %} ] },
    })
});
</script>
```

I'm very new to the whole web development thing, and have no experience with Javascript. Right now all I'm trying to do is set up drag and drop so that only the sample nodes can be moved, and they can only be set as children of a location node. The main stumbling block I seem to be encountering is that I can't figure out how to check if a node has a parent or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying it again today with a fresh mind, I figured it out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#demo1").jstree({
        "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","hotkeys","dnd"],
        "core" : { "initially_open" : [ {% for key, value in samples.items %}"{{key}}", {% endfor %} ] },
        "crrm" : {
            "move" : {
                "check_move" : function(data) {
                    var p = this._get_parent(data.o);
                    //You cannot move a node with no parents
                    if(p == -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    //You cannot move a child to the root
                    else if(!this.get_path(data.np[0])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    //You cannot move a node deeper than 1 level into the tree
                    else if(this.get_path(data.np[0]).length > 1) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
        "dnd" : {
            //I don't know what this does... I was more or less just copying code
            "drop_target" : false,
            "drag_target" : false
        },
    })
});
</script>
```